# Deprecation Warning in my fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a select consist of year so that the fullcalendar can goto a certain year and a button to do it.
Here is my code:

```
$('#btnfilter').on('click', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventLimit: true,
        events: '../js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/events.json.php'
    });
    var year = $('#slctyear').val();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year);
})
```

this code worked but I have an error in console. I've read it but I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: What is the console error you're seeing?

Comment: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]

Comment: Is `$('slctyear')` an input field?

Comment: It is a select. The above code is running. Only, it is depreciated. <select id="slctyear">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying the date you're passing to Full Calendar is in a format that won't be supported down the road. Full Calendar is using a library called [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the date, and MomentJS is changing how it handles dates.

That long Github thread is, in short, saying you need to pass a properly formatted date to Full Calendar.

It appears you're passing a single year (like `2016`) to Full Calendar, like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year);
```

The issue is `year` is not a valid ISO Date. To make it valid, and prevent the error, you need to format the date before it's passed to Full Calendar.

To properly format the date you need to use Javascript's `Date()`. In your case, you want to do:

```
var year = new Date($('#slctyear').val(), 0 , 1);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year);
```

The `Date($('#slctyear').val(), 0 , 1)` part will create an ISO formatted date for midnight on January 1st of whatever year the form input contains.

This will prevent the error.

Comment: An ISO date is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, as well as some variations if time or week is included.  More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)